# I want a table on the right corner that shows the data that i need

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I would like to bring my scrypt from my ToS to TradingView, but i find it very hard to do it since is kinda different. So here i  am asking for some help :)
I've been trying to develop a table where i can see these following intra-day informations even tho i'am in different timeframes:
Current 1min dollar candle (real-time)
Current day gap
Current dollar traded in the day
Open to highest price reached in the day

Thank you in advance!!!!!!

Here is the code I was working on:

```
//@version=5
```

indicator("My script", overlay = true)

tfInput = input.timeframe(defval = "D", title = "Timeframe" )

HTopen = request.security( syminfo.tickerid, tfInput, open)
HTclose = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tfInput, close)

Table_Def = table.new(position = position.top_right, columns = 6,rows = 3,frame_color = color.gray, frame_width = 2,border_color = color.gray,border_width = 1 )

table.cell(Table_Def, column =  0 , row =  0 , text = "Gap %", text_color = color.white)
table.cell(Table_Def, column =  0 , row =  1 , text = str.tostring((HTopen[1]/HTclose[2])-1), text_color = color.white)

table.cell(Table_Def, column =  1 , row =  0 , text = "Open to toptick", text_color = color.white)
table.cell(Table_Def, column =  1 , row =  1 , text = str.tostring((high/open)-1), text_color = color.white)

table.cell(Table_Def, column =  2 , row =  0 , text = "Candle $", text_color = color.white)
table.cell(Table_Def, column =  2 , row =  1 , text = str.tostring(close*volume), text_color = color.white)

table.cell(Table_Def, column =  3 , row =  0 , text = "$ Traded", text_color = color.white)
table.cell(Table_Def, column =  3 , row =  1 , text = str.tostring(volume*ta.vwap), text_color = color.white)

Comment: "I tried to do a table with the informations i needed"
Show the code you tried, and embed a pic of the errored results so someone can figure out what is going on with your script.

Comment: @easleyfixed Here is the code for the 1min candle i was working on it :            

indicator("Current Candle Dollar Volume", overlay = true)

closePrice = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "1", close)

volume1min = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "1", volume)

dollarVolume = closePrice * volume


label.new(x = bar_index, y = high, text = "Dollar Volume: " + str.tostring(dollarVolume), style = label.style_label_down, color = color.red, textcolor = color.white, size = size.normal)

Comment: Update your question and put that code into the question and then highlight and select the code button and it will format it into code someone can edit to assist you.  And you said it puts some lines on the chart .. theres a way to embed a picture of that into this question so someone can assit you.

Comment: @easley Thank you! The problem is that i deleted the previous code since they were not working and now i decied to work on 1 just to make it simple and add 1 by 1.

Comment: @easley I updated my work and seems not wroking yet. I dont understand why is not using the open of the day, the high if the day,  the previous day close and the current day volume * VWAP